# I am little bit confused how can i mix my three function together to make it short

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need an idea how i can join all this function together they have only little difference that is `buyer1 buyer2 buyer3` any idea? thank in advance

it will be helpful because i have many code which look similar and js packer not helping much

```
function buyer1() {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=buyer1&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
function buyer2() {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=buyer2&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
function buyer3() {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=buyer3&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would stop trying to make it short by having those insane variable names `f`, `n`, `z`, `t` removed

Comment: Create a method called buyer and pass a string argument. You can then pass buyer1,buyer2 or buyer3 into the function and dynamically replace the value in the url that you are creating.

Comment: Create one function that takes a parameter for the part(s) that are different between the three functions. At a glance, the only difference that pops out is here `action=buyer3`. So just pass in a number as a parameter and concat it into your string.

Comment: Wow . . . 3 almost identical answers, all at the same time.   LOL

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code-review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a parameter for your `buyer` function, i named it `buyerId`:

```
function buyer(buyerId) {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=buyer" + buyerId + "&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
```

So now,

```
buyer1 = function() { buyer(1) }
buyer2 = function() { buyer(2) }
...
```

Or you can directly call the new buyer function.

Answer (score 5):

pass the buyer ID as a string to the function as a parameter:

```
function buyerX(buyer) {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=" + buyer + "&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}

buyerX("buyer1");
buyerX("buyer2");
buyerX("buyer3");
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass a parameter into the function to indicate the buyer number . . .

```
function buyer(index) {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action=buyer" + index + "&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
```

Just so it's easier to see, here are the two changed lines:

```
function buyer(index) {
```

. . . and . . .

```
data: "action=buyer" + index + "&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z +
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that only thing that differs is the `action` parameter value that is being passed.  Perhaps you could simply pass that value to the function.

```
function buyer(action) {
    var f = $("#buy_id").val();
    var n = $("#buyer_id").val();
    var z = $("#token_id").val();
    var t = $("#buy_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "action="+action+"&pet_id=" + f + "&my_id=" + n + "&token=" + z + "&buy_value=" + t + "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (e) {
            token_id = e.token_id;
            message = e.message;
            value = e.value;
            $("#buy_value").val(value);         
            $("#token_id").val(token_id);
            $("#buyerdialog").fadeIn(300);
            $("#buyerresult").html(message);
        },
        error: function () {}
    })
}
```